# iPhone app's traffic not sniffable

Tags: iphone, reverse-engineering, charles-proxy

I've got quite a bit of experience using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to sniff out traffic being sent out on my iPhones. Almost every app that I choose to reverse engineer has been possible in large part to `cURL` and `Charles`. But, for some reason, this one app called [Link](http://linkmessenger.com/) seems to have a different way of communication with their server. I looked through my entire Chalres session and didn't see any relevant traffic from this app to an API endpoint. I don't have much experience actually making mobile apps, so perhaps there are other ways to process all of the requests that have to be generated upon using the app. But, how could all of the user's data be stored if no requests are being sent from the app to an external server somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charles is an HTTP proxy, it is possible another protocol is being used. Possibly directly using TCP/IP connections.

Wireshark will show all packets in gory detail but you will probably not be able to see encrypted data decrypted without the key.

And the Wireshark UI is something to behold. ;-)

Comment: If they're using a different protocol, then could it successfully be copied with `cURL`?

Comment: Sorry, I only use curl with http for testing and know little about it. The docs state these protocols: "DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP" which are all high level, at least above TCP/IP. Wireshark is free other than the cost of getting to know it, at least you will be able to see the actual packets being sent, probably more than you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

If the app runs on SSL you wouldn't be able to sniff any traffic either way. I design my apps that way at least. Could this be the case? Does it use port 443 instead of port 80?

Comment: I installed Charle's SSL certificate to bypass that whole issue. I can see SSL traffic being sent from my phone for lots of other apps.

Comment: If you filter all outgoing traffic for the IP of your phone, surely there must be something somewhere.

Comment: If an app is check the certificates then if can detect the charles certificate and cancel the request. Most banking apps do this, if they don't you should probably not have an account at this bank ;)

Comment: Yeah, but if it cancels the request then I wouldn't be able to use it, right? I can still use this app normally even while all traffic is being sent through Charles on my MacBook

Comment: How do you configure your certificates exactly? I am not able to detect traffic in some of the app after login page. What is possible config which can detect the sniffer? also how you set the proxies with charles?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Have a look at this post:
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/03/ssl-pinning-for-increased-app-security/

SSL pinning might be the answer.

Comment: But, again, this doesn't explain why you can still use the app.

Comment: Was thinking the exact same thing.

Comment: As Zaph says this could indicate that it isn't using HTTP.
If you just capture all traffic from your iPhone, what destination ports do you get?